# Geo location & Original tweets filter

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to get data for tweets which I am able to obtain using the following code. However, I would also like to get the **location** and **original tweets** instead of retweets. Please suggest on how to go about it.

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd

####input your credentials here
consumer_key= 'XXXX'
consumer_secret= 'XXXX'
access_token = 'XXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('ua.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#RamMandir",count=100,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2017-04-03").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```